# gcc inline assembler shift left problem

Tags: gcc, assembly

I'm having trouble compiling the code below. It may also have logical errors, please help. thanks,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int shifted_value;
    int value = 2;

    __asm__("shll %%eax,%1;" : "=a" (shifted_value): "a" (value));

    cout<<shifted_value<<endl;

    return 0 ;
}
```

The error is:

Error: suffix or operands invalid for `shl'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should look like

```
__asm__(("shll %%cl, %%eax;"
            : "=a" (shifted_value)
            : "a" (shifted_value), "c" (value)
           );
```

Credit for correct code goes to the other answer for pointing out that the operands were in the incorrect order.
You dont need to specify eax as clobbered because eax is an output register.

Comment: shll ought to be OK for "shift left longword". not sure, though

Comment: I'm only familiar with x86 so there might be a shll in some other instruction set but as far as I remember its shl and shr in x86.

Comment: Well theres also shld and shrd for doubles but I don't think he wants either of those. I could be wrong though just never seen shll

Comment: I got it working like this                                      __asm__("shld %%eax, 1;" : "=a" (shifted_value): "a" (value));                        but then it crashes.

Comment: you should be using shl not shld, you're using an int value the problem it crahses is because you're overriding EAX and not telling gcc that so it continues as if nothing happened and crashes because its assumption that EAX contained some value was incorrect

Comment: __asm__("shl %%eax,1;" : "=a" (shifted_value): "a" (value): "%eax");

Comment: I tried the above and that didn't compile. I also tried      __asm__("shl %%eax, 1;" : "=a" (shifted_value): "b" (value));

Comment: What error do you get? it might be %%eax instead of just %eax, try that instead.

Comment: I'm getting this error:                                                In function 'int main()':|
error: can't find a register in class 'AREG' while reloading 'asm'|
error: 'asm' operand has impossible constraints|

Comment: I got this error by using %%eax in the last parameter: error: unknown register name '%%eax' in 'asm'|

Comment: I deleted my answer because I found out that %1 can actually be correct... studying up on this inline assembly syntax now, I rarely use it. sorry about giving bad info.

Comment: That's alright I thought the same thing but it can be done both ways.

Comment: It works as is in my answer now, not sure why it doesnt like the clobber list on your machine.

Comment: Ok I realized my mistake, =r is registered as an output register from eax. GCC already knows that you clobbered it.

Comment: Jesus, you were spot-on with your observation that %eax had not been initialized. +1 for that.

Comment: I believe your implementation is correct so the OP should switch the answer to yours I forgot that the operands were in the wrong order so mine probably prints incorrect output. If I'm correct mine should print 64 which is definitely not 2 << 1 which is 4. Also havent seen shll in any x86 instruction set but its probably because the l is a prefix (I do instruction encoding and longword is an opcode prefix instead)

Answer (score 3):

it can work with shll also, shll being the GNU at&t mnemonic for "shift left longword". However, the invalid operand error is due to the operand needing to come first! I found this out when I googled up these sources: http://meplayer.googlecode.com/svn-history/r23/trunk/meplayer/src/filters/transform/mpcvideodec/ffmpeg/libavcodec/cabac.h. I also used the excellent http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s6

Here is one way that works, taking into account Jesus Ramos's observation that shifted_value needs to be initialized:

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ cat test.cpp; make test; ./test
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int shifted_value = 1;
    char value = 2;

    __asm__("shll %%cl, %%eax;"
            : "=a" (shifted_value)
            : "a" (shifted_value), "c" (value)
           );

    cout<<shifted_value<<endl;

    return 0 ;
}

g++     test.cpp   -o test
4
```

Comment: Youre right somewhat but its shld also. But when it runs now it crashes.

Comment: at&t notation always gets me sometimes, I've been doing too much kernel level stuff and x86 that I usually forget operands are backwards in inline asm :\